# Imagen en Scroll

Tags: jquery, css3, scroll

Necesito poner una imagen en el scroll, en vez del scroll por defecto.

Saben si se puede poner una imagen en el scroll? ya sea con css o jquery

Gracias!

Comment: Hola Mario, bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español. Te recomiendo que leas [ask] y completes el [tour] para aprender cómo funciona el sitio (y con ello conseguir tu primera medalla). Esta pregunta necesita algunas mejoras: mayor descripción del problema, especificación de qué tipo de scroll estás usando (¿uno propio?¿un plugin?¿jQuery UI?¿Bootstrap?), 
y algo de código.

Answer (score 2):

Solo debes usar css para posicionar el elemento como [fixed](http://www.w3schools.com/Css/pr_class_position.asp):

```
.fixedElement {
    background-color: #c0c0c0;
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    width:100%;
    z-index:100;
}
```

Comment: Hola Jr Jimnz, bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español. Te recomiendo que completes el [tour] y que leas [answer] en el centro de ayuda, donde encontrarás consejos para mejorar tus respuestas (y qué tipo de preguntas sería mejor no responder).